# capistrano 'executing bundle install' not completing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm following the instructions of Ryan Bates' Deploy to a VPS Railscast to deploy my app to an ubuntu cloud server on Digital Ocean. After I run `cap deploy:cold`, a few different commands are executed successfully, but then when it gets to 'executing bundle:install' it stays in 'executing command' mode for a very long time without throwing any kind of error or completing, like this

```
  command finished in 171ms
  * 2013-06-27 12:57:07 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/michaelj/apps/qbruby2/releases/20130627195707 && bundle install --gemfile /home/michaelj/apps/qbruby2/releases/20130627195707/Gemfile --path /home/michaelj/apps/qbruby2/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["192.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [192.241.129.33] executing command
```

I looked at some other people's deployments (on Stackoverflow) and saw that this command usually completes in a matter of milliseconds. My whole gemfile has less than 20 gems (i.e. the standard gems plus a few extras), yet deployment has been paused here for more than 20 minutes.

Can you suggest what I might do?

Comment: What if you try to run the command in ssh into your server to see if some issue is presented?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain in more detail? I don't know if you mean "run the command inside my server" or run it "into" my server

Comment: run `ssh youruser@your_server_addr_at_digital_ocean`. In the ssh shell type: `cd /home/michaelj/apps/qbruby2/releases/20130627195707 && bundle install --gemfile /home/michaelj/apps/qbruby2/releases/20130627195707/Gemfile --path /home/michaelj/apps/qbruby2/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test`

Comment: not working. Do you know where I might look to check for Rails errors during bundle install when deploying to a VPS?

Comment: In the same console where you are deploying. What do you mean with not working? Does not exists the folders? The command freezes?

Comment: After I opened a new shell session and ran that command, I couldn't get the rest of the commands in the Railscast (about nginx) to run properly https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10328969/railscast.png I destroyed that server, set it up again, and am in the same position. The `executing bundle:install` won't finish running

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=comments  In comments some people have the same issue I think, try the solutions posted

Comment: Can you post a gist of your deploy.rb file

Comment: @AustinLin https://gist.github.com/MikeOnRails/48141301b2a223ba1988

Comment: @Aguardientico I've read the comments but no one's having the same problem

Comment: @Leahcim try to verify the db credentials, verify that you can connect to db, the similar issues are problems with mysql

Comment: can you post your gem file. also I would try copying your gem file to a temp directory and running bundle install on the server, see how long that takes

Comment: @AustinLin here's the gemfile http://pastebin.com/KkvJd7hU . Do I just make a random directory, drop in gemfile with nothing else and it should work by running bundle install?

Comment: yep, you should just be able to run bundler in any directory with a Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

The first step in troubleshooting these issues, is ensuring you can run the commands remotely.

Thankfully, capistrano outputs the commands it's trying to execute. Then you can do copy/paste over to the server.

In my experience, i've seen the ssh server terminating ssh sessions for long running processes. (that is migrations or bundle install for example) For those cases, there are a few options (modifying sshd_config on the server has worked for me)

add these lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 5